# Android map not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I have an app, that uses google play servises and google map.

When I upload it from eclipse, map works, and gets lastKnownLocation correct.

But when I export signed apk, map doesn't work.

Why can it be?

here's my code:

```
public class NavigationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationSource, LocationListener, OnMyLocationChangeListener {

private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
private LocationManager lManager;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    lManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lManager.requestLocationUpdates(lManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true), 1, 1000, this);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(){
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(50.088785,14.418675), 15, 60, 0);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));
    }
}

public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener){mListener = listener;}

public void deactivate(){mListener = null;}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.onLocationChanged(location);
    }
}
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location){
    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.onLocationChanged(location);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if(lManager != null){
        lManager.requestLocationUpdates(lManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true), 1, 1000, this);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    if(lManager != null){
        lManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a key for the signed build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export a signed apk the signature of the package changes, which is used to authenticate your app with Google. You have to generate a new API key with the signature of the signed apk.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Got the SHA1 from exporting signed app window, and now map works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your api key, it should be generated from your own key. Also follow http://goo.gl/dvs0yo to generate the key.